# Problems with C# bitmap.clone() speed difference due to bitmap loading method

Tags: c#, bitmap, clone, performance-testing

I have question about different Clone() speed between `new bitmap(ImagePath)` and `new Bitmap(new Bitmap(ImagePath))`.

This is my code.

```
//case1 
Bitmap dst = new bitmap(ImagePath)

//case2
Bitmap orgimg = new bitmap(ImagePath);
Bitmap dst = new Bitmap((bitmap)orgimg.Clone());
```

---

```
Bitmap crop = null;

time.start();
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
    Crop = dst.Clone(new Rectangle(10,10,10,10), dst.PixelFormat);
    Crop.Dispose();
}
time.stop();
```

Case1 take Over 2000ms, case2 take ~10ms.

The Image is 1600*1200, 24bit BMP file. I test same Clone loop, 500times.

What the difference between `new bitmap(ImagePath)` and `new Bitmap(new Bitmap(ImagePath))`?